# pgrep multiple process names

Tags: regex, linux, shell, grep, procps

I want to get PIDs of two or more processes using "pgrep" command in Linux.

As we know pgrep syntax is

```
pgrep [options] <pattern>
```

Here is a hypothetical command which should return PIDs of two processes whose names are **process1** and **process2** respectively.

```
pgrep process1 OR process2
```

What should be the pattern that needs to be used to achieve the above?

Comment: what are the real process names you need to grep?

Comment: The real process names are nginx and java

Comment: From `man pgrep`: `pgrep [options] pattern` and `pattern: Specifies an Extended Regular Expression for matching against the process names or command lines.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
pgrep 'process1|process2'
```

Example:

```
 -->pgrep 'atd|cron'
1078
1093

 -->ps -eaf |grep -E 'atd|cron'
daemon    1078     1  0 Aug08 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/atd -f
root      1093     1  0 Aug08 ?        00:00:19 /usr/sbin/cron -f
xxxx  14364  9597  0 11:56 pts/2    00:00:00 grep -E atd|cron
```

Comment: Be careful, as this is totally wrong. Pgrep uses regexp matching, so `atd|cron` can match not only atd & cron but for instance rpc.statd or crond.

Comment: Its not wrong. Idea for this answer is to tell OP how to use Or condition. When pipe is used for OR condition,  it was implied that regex is used. Yes, they need to use word boundaries to prevent false positive.

Comment: You can just use exact match like this `pgrep -x 'atd|cron'`, or `pgrep '^(atd|cron)$'`.